# ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and package:modal_bottom_sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

> Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
> ../…/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4
> import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
../…/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:28
.push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
../…/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:50

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;

  ```
    ^
  ```

: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
../…/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:102
.push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
../…/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:125

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
  ^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/vannak/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/vannak/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12m 31s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a same issue after upgrading flutter new version 3.7.0 yesterday. It is caused by using ModalBottomSheet package from pub.dev.

You have to add below to your pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependency_overrides:
  modal_bottom_sheet:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/danReynolds/modal_bottom_sheet.git
      path: modal_bottom_sheet
```

**DO NOT DELETE** your modal_bottom_sheet and just **COPY and PASTE below your dependencies.**

Comment: Remember that it is only a temporary measure for now.

Answer (score 7):

Under pubspec.yml add below dependency override function

```
dependency_overrides:
 modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
```

Then its work fine : Enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let's understand this type of issue. If you notice the error

> `ModalBottomSheetRoute` is imported from both `package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart` and  `package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart`.

So it is telling you are getting `ModalBottomSheetRoute` from two different packages.

Now if you like to use material bottomSheet, you can remove this import
`package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart` .

but If you like to use this package class. You can do

- using `as` prefix

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart' as modalSheet;

.....
    modalSheet.ModalBottomSheetRoute(
      builder: (context) =>
```

- or you can hide `ModalBottomSheetRoute` of material

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute;
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
```

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute;
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';

this fixed my issue. thanks