# Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: Exception: Failed to bundle asset files

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, apk

I have modified the pubspec.yamal with https://stackoverflow.com/a/75254540/20101165 to solve the "ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and package:modal_bottom_sheet" issue, after modifying the file, I tried to build the apk, but the response was an error as follows :

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: packages/html_editor_enhanced/summernote.html.

This asset was included from package html_editor_enhanced.
Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: Exception: Failed to bundle asset files.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\Program Files\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'E:\Program Files\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           75.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

anyone can help me to solve the issue ?